# Is it possible to set OpenCV Mouse Call back on two windows simultaneously?

Tags: opencv

Is it possible to set OpenCV Mouse call-back on two different windows simultaneously such that it can decide which window the mouse is on ?

Comment: Which language are you looking for?

Comment: I'm working on C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int, void* userData)
{
    int * windowID = (int*)userData;
    std::cout << "mouse in window: " << (*windowID) << std::endl;

    if((*windowID) == 1)
    {
        // do whatever you want to do for window 1
    }
    else if((*windowID) == 2)
    {
        // do whatever you want to do for window 2
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/Lenna.png");

    cv::imshow("input1", input);
    cv::imshow("input2", input);

    int id1 = 1;
    int id2 = 2;
    cv::setMouseCallback("input1", &onMouse, &id1);
    cv::setMouseCallback("input2", &onMouse, &id2);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Those are my outputs (unfortunately mouse cursor not visible...):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome. But a little error. You cant compare pointer and integer. So change it to  *windowID == 1, in your onmouse function and everything is set.

Comment: thx for the hint, I edited the if-else part without testing. I'll fix that!